# Sequelize - update query with returning: true succeeds but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following function which I use to update the URL to the user's profile pic -

```
const updateProfilePic = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.param("id");
  if (userId) {
    const targetPath = `...`;
    User.update(
      {
        profilePic: targetPath
      },
      { where: { id: userId }, returning: true }
    )
      .then(updatedUser => {
        console.log(updatedUser);
        res.json(updatedUser);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send({ error: error });
      });
  }
};
```

This updates the DB successfully - however `then` obtains `[ undefined, 1 ]` as the `updatedUser` instead of the user data - if I remove the `returning : true` flag, it just returns `[ 1 ]`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - I'm trying to obtain the user object so that I can pass it on to the client.

Comment: what db are you using with sequelize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume you are not using Postgres.

The `returning` property in options is **only supported in Postgres**.

`Update()` returns an array with one or two elements. The first element is the number of affected rows. The second array element is only supported in postgres and will return the updated row.

So you are getting the **1** returned which is the number of rows updated.

[Docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update)