# Sequelize update() with 'returning: true' not finding Types if code is in NPM package

Tags: typescript, azure-functions, sequelize.js, azure-sql-database, tedious

I am trying to get sequelize@6.32.1 to return an updated object (Azure Function v4, Typescript, tedious@16.1.0, Azure SQL Server) as per update() option `returning: true`.

See the commented out line below:

```
async update(query: any, value: Partial<T>, transaction?: Transaction) {
    const err = new Error();
    try {
        const model = await this.create(transaction);
        return model.update(value, {
            where: query,
            // returning: true,
            transaction: transaction
        });
    } catch (ex: any) {
        err.message = 'Unable to update query:' + JSON.stringify(query) + ' value:' + JSON.stringify(value) + '\n' + this.logTableError(ex);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

The class is an abstract wrapper for all my models and I compile and deploy it as a private NPM package that I reuse in multiple projects successfully.

But if I uncomment that line, I get the following errors in the projects where I use that package.

**NOTE**: the NPM project still compiles perfectly fine and it's only projects that use the package that are affected.

[image]

If I look at the types (*.ts.d) file in `node_modules` the issue is associated with the types used by Sequelize hooks that are added to make the cascade `update()` work.

Both the NPM package and my project using the package have `@types/sequelize@4.28.15`.

Can anyone advise please why these types are getting the error:

> Cannot find name '*'

[image]

Comment: Can anyone corroborate that the `returning` options for `update()` is only valid in POSTGRES please?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883687/sequelize-update-query-with-returning-true-succeeds-but-returns-undefined

Comment: This answer suggests it does work with Azure SQL Server:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712294/sequelize-azure-sql-database-rollback